# Importing values from .CSV file to Python script

Tags: python, import

Im working on Path Planning of Drone using GPS co ordinates given in .CSV file , How to import GPS co ordintaes from .CSV file to my Python script directly??

Comment: When you say "importing" what do you mean by that, to read into a data-structure like other files? To actually use the `import` statement? Something else? And what have you tried? Doesn't Python come with a CSV module as standard?

Comment: Also please don't tag unrelated languages (or unrelated tags at all).

Answer (score 2):

taking the locations csv file having lattitute and longitde values as:
[locations.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPNWw.png)
PFB piece of code:

```
import csv

filename = 'D:\Python\location.csv'
n=0

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fields = next(csvreader)

    for row in csvreader:
        n = n + 1
        print('location {} --> {}:{}\t{}:{}'.format(n,fields[0],row[0], fields[1],row[1]) )
```

Output:

```
location 1 --> Latitude:40.741895       Longitude:-73.989308
location 2 --> Latitude:41.741895       Longitude:-72.989308
location 3 --> Latitude:42.741895       Longitude:-71.989308
location 4 --> Latitude:43.741895       Longitude:-70.989308
location 5 --> Latitude:44.741895       Longitude:-74.989308
```

Comment: please accept as answer if it solves your question.

Comment: i am new to python... so please can you tell me how to use these values in anather python  script? for example if i want to access latitude 40.741895 in my program from .csv file can i access it as latitude[1]=location[1] after executing above lines of program? or is there any other option?

Comment: you can create a list variable like `rows = []` and for each `row` in `csvreader`, you can keep on appending the values in `rows` list (`rows.append(row)`). Finally you will have a list of list like `[[lat1,long1],[lat2,long2],...]`, then you can itterate and take lattitude and longitudes as required. for more details, please have a look at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-csv-files-python/

Answer (score 1):

PFB sample code:

```
import csv

filename = 'D:\Python\location.csv'
rows = []

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fields = next(csvreader)
    print(fields)

    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
        rows.append(row)
print(rows)
```

output:

```
['Latitude', 'Longitude']
['40.741895', '-73.989308']
['41.741895', '-72.989308']
['42.741895', '-71.989308']
['43.741895', '-70.989308']
['44.741895', '-74.989308']
[['40.741895', '-73.989308'], ['41.741895', '-72.989308'], ['42.741895', '-71.989308'], ['43.741895', '-70.989308'], ['44.741895', '-74.989308']]
```

Comment: Please add your output to your question as text instead of an image. This is important for the search-algorithms.

Comment: there you go @wuerfelfreak

Comment: Way better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at pandas in case you want to do more than merely iterate through the data: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

As a further extension there's also geopandas that is supposed to make working with geospatial data easier.